# Suggest very fast (microseconds) java logging?

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, real-time

I want to track events in my sound processing multithreading app. It has some bug manifestating only under certain circumstances.

If I am trying to use conventional logging (slf4j and log4j to console intercepted by Eclipse), bug disappears since logging commands introduce millisecond level delays and everything goes differently.

How to make logging go faster (hundreds or thousands of times) or to log other way?

**UPDATE**

Now using logback with file appender and it is sufficient yet.

Comment: Basically - you need to get file IO out of your face. Try appending to a `StringBuilder` or `ArrayList<String>` or to a `BlockingQueue<String>`.

Comment: What about writing custom `Appender` and storing log messages in-memory, or maybe even asynchronously?

Comment: except things already mentioned, I'd give a try to logback http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html (as it might be more performant as log4j)

Comment: @Peter +1 Yes, logback is the state of the art when it comes to logging performance.

Comment: I might be contradicting myself :) but on the other hand author of log4j/logback already started log4j 2 (for performance see: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html), but it has no stable release yet, so might be a bit buggy

Comment: You may consider logging asynchronously, too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is simple: never print **anything** to the Eclipse console. Write to a file only and view the file after all is done. Log4j itself is quite performant.

Comment: Writing to a file isn't also slow in this case?

Comment: Nowhere near the slowness of Eclipse console. It's in the microseconds range.

Answer (score 2):

You might find writing text to a file is fast enough so I would start with that.

If you need sub-microsecond text or binary logging you can use [Java Chronicle](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle) which I wrote.

Comment: hey, the second part seems like advertisement for your product :), but hey, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @PeterButkovic True, that is what it was designed for.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go to the nanosecond level you must go asynchronous, meaning that the disk I/O is performed by a separate thread. Lock-free queues (i.e. [Disruptor](http://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/), [CoralQueue](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/category/coralqueue/), etc.) provide pipelining between threads very efficiently, without producing any garbage for the GC.

For a very fast (~ 100 nanos / msg) logger you can check [CoralLog](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/category/corallog/).

For a very fast (~ 70 nanos /msg) read/write store you can check [CoralStore](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/category/coralstore/).

**Disclaimer:** I am one of the developers of CoralQueue, CoralLog and CoralStore.